# Latex function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, double, latex

I want to use latex function in Matlab 2013b. Using of this function is easy and it works as I expected:

```
s = sym('s');
latex((s+1)/3)

ans =

\frac{s}{3} + \frac{1}{3}
```

Than I have a simple matrix and latex function return following error:

```
A = [ 0 1 0; 1 -2 1; -2 4 -2];
latex(A)
Undefined function 'latex' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

Another example:

```
latex(3/4 + 4)
Undefined function 'latex' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

In works with symbolic variables but does not work with integers. Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation: **LaTeX representation of symbolic expression**

Do:

```
latex(sym(A))
latex(sym(3/4+4)) % But this will return the result of the numbers, so \frac{19}{4}
```

Comment: Thanks and what about the case I don't want to modify the expression? ie I need to get \frac{3}{4} + 4

Comment: @user1313386 Im not very sure you can... I guess something like strcat(latex(sym(3/4)),'+4) or something like this...